# Weird code interaction when scanning and printing chars in C

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, ascii

When you declare two variables char a,b; and then you use first 'a' and then 'b',it prints only b, but if you declare it 'b' then 'a', it has no problem printing both in ASCII,the point of the program is to read 121 and 120 and to print yx. the problem - https://prnt.sc/pr5nww
and if you swap them -https://prnt.sc/pr5mt5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char a,b;

    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d",&b);

    printf("%c",a);
    printf("%c",b);
}
```

Comment: The format `%d` is to read (or print) **`int`** values. A pointer to `char` (like `&a`) is not equal to a pointer to `int`. Because of the mismatching `scanf` format and argument types you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: the point of the program is to read 121 and 120 and to print yx 
sorry for not saying

Comment: [... the input item ... is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. ... If this object does not have an appropriate type ... the behaviour is undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10)

Comment: The easy solution is to remember that values of types smaller than `int` will be promoted to `int` when used in a vararg function (like e.g. `printf`). That means you can read with `scanf` and `%d` into an `int` variable, and then use the `%c` format when printing. It should work like you expect.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a confusing situation.  When it comes to mixing `char` and `int` values (as you might do when investigating the numeric values of characters in a character set), it turns out the rules for `scanf` and `printf` are almost completely different.

First let's look at the `scanf` lines:

```
char a,b;
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
```

This is, in a word, wrong.  The `%d` format in `scanf` is for scanning `int` values *only*.  You cannot use `%d` to input a value of type `char`.  If you want to input a character, the format for that is `%c` (although it'll input it as a character, not a number).

So you'd need to change this to

```
char a,b;
scanf("%c",&a);
scanf("%c",&b);
```

Now you can type characters like `A` and `$` and `3` and have them read into your `char` variables `a` and `b`.  (Actually, you're going to have additional problems if you hit the Return key between typing the characters for `a` and `b`, but that's a different story.)

When it comes to printing the characters out, you have a little more freedom.  Your lines

```
printf("%c",a);
printf("%c",b);
```

are fine.  And if you wanted to see the integer character-set values associated with the characters, you could have typed

```
printf("%d",a);
printf("%d",b);
```

and that would have worked, too.  This is because when you call `printf` (and other functions ike it), there are some automatic conversions that take place: types `char` and `short int` are automatically promoted to (passed as) `int`, and type `float` is promoted to `double`.  But these automatic conversions happen only for *values* of those types (as when calling `printf`).  There a=is no such conversion when you're passing *pointers to* these types, as when calling `scanf`.

What if you wanted to read numbers, not characters?  That is, what if you wanted to input the number 65 and see it get printed as capital `A`?  There are several possible ways to do that.

The first way would be to continue to use `%d` in your `scanf` call, but change the type of your variables to `int`:

```
int a,b;
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
```

Now you can print `a` and `b` out using either `%c` or `%d`, and it'll work fine.

You could also use a temporary `int` variable, before reassigning to `char`, like this:

```
char a,b;
int tmp
scanf("%d",&tmp);
a = tmp;
scanf("%d",&tmp);
b = tmp;
```

The final, lesser-known and somewhat more obscure way, is to use the `h` modifier.  If you say

```
char a,b;
scanf("%hhd",&a);
scanf("%hhd",&b);
```

now you're telling `scanf`, "I want to read decimal digits, but the target variable is a `char`, not an `int`."
And, again, you can print `a` and `b` out using either `%c` or `%d`, and it'll work fine.

Comment: the point of the program is to read 121 and 120 and to print yx sorry for not saying

Comment: ok, but even if i scan them with %hhd and print with %c, when first you declare 'a' its not printed, but if you declare first  'b', prints them both

Comment: @vasilvazonov That I don't understand.  What compiler are you using?  Did you try one of the other options?  `%hhd` is a  *very* obscure input specifier for `scanf`, and it wouldn't surprise me if some vendors implement it incorrectly, such that it ends up having similar problems as plain `%d` in this case.  (That problem, if it's not obvious, is that if `scanf` writes more than one byte of data to `&a` or `&b`, it will typically overwrite nearby variables, causing results such as you've experienced.)

Comment: i use VS code and have tried Code::Blocks, and have tried the code on different pc, and still if i declare 'a' first it's not printed - @SteveSummit

Comment: @vasilvazonov Sorry, then, I'm not sure what additional problem you're having.  I tested `char a,b;
scanf("%hhd",&a);
scanf("%hhd",&b);
` on my computer, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: ok, its possible, but i have the problem -  http://prntscr.com/pr5nww
and if you swap them - http://prntscr.com/pr5mt5
@SteveSummit

Comment: @vasilvazonov Use one of the other two solutions I suggested, then.  `scanf` is a toy, anyway.  (It's square training wheels.)

Answer (score 1):

> *the point of the program is to read 121 and 120 and to print yx*

Do

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char a, b;

  /* Scan into the half of the half of an int (the leading blank 
     makes scanf() eat whitespaces): */
  scanf(" %hhd", &a); 
  scanf(" %hhd", &b);

  /* Print the half of the half of an int: */
  printf("%hhd", a);
  printf("%hhd", b);
}
```

To print the characters literally do the printing part like this:

```
  ...

  printf("%c", a);
  printf("%c", b);
}
```

Comment: I think of `h` as standing for *s**h**ort*, not ***h**alf*.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Does it? Made sense, yes. I just had no clue what it stood for, so made up the "half"-thing for myself, to help remember it ... :}

Comment: I think he rather wants `printf("%c", a);`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: I feel your assumption is contradicting the "*xy*" in "*print yx*". As `%c` would only give "*x*" or "*y*".

Comment: Ahh ... well ookay.

Comment: @alk I was just lazy: `printf("%c", a); printf("%c", b);`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Seems I completely misunderstood the question. :}

Comment: @alk not completely IMO, your `scanf` part is OK to me.

Comment: @alk And yet the `scanf %hhd` part of your answer is completely correct (and has gotten upvoted before my tl;dr version :-\ )

Comment: ok, but even if i scan them with %hhd and print with %c, when first you declare 'a' its not printed, but if you declare first 'b', prints them both @alk

Comment: the problem -  http://prntscr.com/pr5nww
and if i swap them - http://prntscr.com/pr5mt5